# Ionic 3 native deeplinking

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, deep-linking

Managed to install and setup the native deeplinking module for Ionic.

App loads up fine even in cold state, where it is fully shutdown.

However, my route doesn't take me to the correct page. It just displays the last page the app was one, or the main page if it starts the application from cold state.

**app.component.ts**

```
...
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks';
import { Detail1Page } from '../pages/layout/app1/detail1/detail1';
...
constructor(private deeplinks: Deeplinks.........
...
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
this.splashScreen.hide();
this.deeplinks.route({
  '/item/:itemId': Detail1Page
}).subscribe((match) => {
    console.log('Successfully matched route', JSON.stringify(match));
  }, (nomatch) => {
    console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', JSON.stringify(nomatch));
  });
}
...
```

The console log shows:

```
Successfully matched route {"$args":{"itemId":"9"},"$link":{"path":"/item/9","queryString":"","fragment":"","host":"my.app.com","url":"https://my.app.com/item/9","scheme":"https"}}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks';
...
providers: [
    Deeplinks,
...
```

**detail1.ts**

```
...
this.itemId = this.navParams.get('itemId');
...
```

Your help is greatly appreciated - been working on this the whole day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into that same problem just yesterday...

In my case, I didn't register my page everywhere that your supposed to in my app.module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyPage)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyPage
  ]
})
export class MyPageModule {}
```

For me I was missing the `IonicPageModule.forChild` reference.
Here is the documentation page where it talks about setting a page up for deeplinking.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/#usage

Comment: I gave up on ionic’s dreplinking and went to branch.io. Best thing i did :)

Comment: Ooo that (branch.io) looks sweet, I'm going to have to check that out. Hopefully my answer can help someone else down the road.

Comment: Branch is amazin and easy to integrate. Youll love it.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late but still, it can be helpful for someone. I am redirecting the user after subscribing so you can put more logic if the user is logged in on not or so you can change things accordingly

```
this.deeplinks.route({
  '/item/:itemId': {}
}).subscribe(match => { 
    console.log('Successfully matched route' + JSON.stringify(match));
    this.nav.push(Detail1Page, { issueId: match.$args.issueId});

  }
}, nomatch => {
  console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match' + JSON.stringify(nomatch));
});
```